# Display Badges depending on Points Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm having a hard time displaying correct badges in a users view. I have a points system where users can earn points depending on various tasks that they do. I implemented a @if, @elseif system in my view to display certain badges(a image) depending on how many points a user has. So if a user has 100 points, one badge will display, if a user has 250 points another badge will display with the old badge too.

here is the view:

```html
@if ($user->points->points >= 100)
     <img src="{{ $user->ShowPointsFor100() }}" class="ui small circular image">
@elseif ($user->points->points >= 250)
     <img src="{{ $user->ShowPointsFor100() }}" class="ui small circular image">
     <img src="{{ $user->ShowPointsFor250() }}" class="ui small circular image">
@endif
```

My problem is even if a user has more than 250 points or greater only the first badge(image) will show. How do I make it so that 2 badges show?

Here is an image:
[image: Users Badges]

Comment: Reverse your order and check higher first

Comment: wow yep, thats wired but ok